# jQuery Datatables Stuck on "Processing"

Tags: jquery, datatables

**UPDATE:  Per the suggestions in the comments, I have updated the data table coding to use the mRender and mData methods.  I am still having the same issue outlined below. The code has been updated to reflect the change**

The issue I am having is very strange.  When I load a page that uses jQuery datatables locally, the table populates correctly.  When I move the page to my remote hosting the datatable only shows the "Processing" box and never loads the data. Locally, I am running WAMP server, the hosted server is running Linux. To throw another curve ball out there, it DID function on the remote server, but suddenly stopped working without any changes made to the code or server setup. There is no alert for any errors.

Here is the code for the datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#properties").dataTable( {
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "bAutoWidth": false,
  "sAjaxSource": "index.php?option=com_protools&task=anlypropertiesajax&tmpl=component",
  "aoColumns":[
            { "mData":"0", "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
            return "<a href='.$module.'?task=anlyShowprop&propid=" + data + ">" + data + "</a>";
              }
           },
          { "mData": function ( source, type, val ) { 
              return "<a href='.$module.'?task=anlyShowprop&propid=" + source["0"] + ">" + source["1"] + "</a>";
             }
    },

          { "mData": function ( source, type, val ) { return source["2"]+ "<br />" + source["3"] + ", " + source["4"]+ "<br /> "+source["5"];}},
          { "mData":"7"},
          { "mData":"8"},
          { "mData":"9"},
          { "mData":"10"},
          { "mData":"11"},
          { "mData":"12"},      
          { "mData":"13"},
          { "mData":"14"}   
       ]
} );
} );
```

The JSON returned is valid (validated on http://jsonlint.com/).

Any thoughts on why the table would populate locally, but not on the remote server?  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Browser (ex Chrome) `F12` > Console log, error message appear ?

Comment: Here is the output from the console

Comment: 7=true&bSortable_8=true&bSortable_9=true&bSortable_10=true&_=1377536927132 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
send jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
j.defaults.fnServerData jquery.dataTables.min.js:132
wa jquery.dataTables.min.js:46
x jquery.dataTables.min.js:38
K jquery.dataTables.min.js:52
O jquery.dataTables.min.js:86
ba jquery.dataTables.min.js:58
(anonymous function) jquery.dataTables.min.js:127
p.extend.each jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.fn.p.each jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
j jquery.dataTables.min.js:116
(anonymous function) proanalysis:86
n jquery.min.js:2

Comment: Continued..
o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B
Error in event handler: Error: Error calling method on NPObject. event_bindings:325
Event.dispatch_ event_bindings:325
Event.dispatch event_bindings:340
(anonymous function) miscellaneous_bindings:167
target.(anonymous function) extensions::SafeBuiltins:20
Event.dispatchToListener event_bindings:334
Event.dispatch_ event_bindings:317
Event.dispatch event_bindings:340
dispatchOnMessage

Comment: The error is server-side `500 (Internal Server Error)` show the cpmplete URL without your domain if you want and show your work server-side, because the problem is here. NOTE : `fnRender` is deprecated, use `mRender` instead. See the doc http://datatables.net/ref#fnRender

Comment: I have adjusted the jQuery code to use mRender/mData to populate the data table.  It works great locally, but still hangs up at "processing" on the hosted.  Below is an updated console output...

Comment: GETindex.php/index.php?option=com_protools&tas…7=true&bSortable_8=true&bSortable_9=true&bSortable_10=true&_=1377719847457 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
send jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
j.defaults.fnServerData jquery.dataTables.min.js:132
wa jquery.dataTables.min.js:46
x jquery.dataTables.min.js:38
K jquery.dataTables.min.js:52
O jquery.dataTables.min.js:86
ba jquery.dataTables.min.js:58
(anonymous function) jquery.dataTables.min.js:127
p.extend.each jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.fn.p.each jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
j jquery.dataTables.min.js:116

Comment: Continued....(anonymous function) proanalysis:86
n jquery.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B jquery.min.js:2

Comment: Updated jQuery.... 
`
{ "mData":"0", "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
return "<a href='.$module.'?task=anlyShowprop&propid=" + data + ">" + data + "</a>";}},
{ "mData": function ( source, type, val ) {
return "<a href='.$module.'?task=anlyShowprop&propid=" + source["0"] + ">" + source["1"] + "</a>";}},
{ "mData": function ( source, type, val ) { return source["2"]+ "<br />" + source["3"] + ", " + source["4"]+ "<br /> "+source["5"];}},{ "mData":"7"},
{ "mData":"8"},
{ "mData":"9"},
{ "mData":"10"},
{ "mData":"11"},
{ "mData":"12"},    
{ "mData":"13"},
{ "mData":"14"}]
});});
`

Comment: update your post instead add comment.. we cannot read them Thx

Comment: @Olivier Thanks for the suggestion to update.  I was hoping the comment would format differently.  The update has been made in the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you also use the background page，Maybe you can solve this problem like this：
When you return to the data structure of the paging information，You can reset the returned sEcho to 0，like this:
eg:

```
    dataSource.setsEcho(0);//I try set 0，It's work for me，you can try
    dataSource.setAaData(tempList);
    dataSource.setiTotalDisplayRecords(totalNum);
    dataSource.setiTotalRecords(totalNum);
```