# datatable stuck on processing when click on page index

Tags: ajax, node.js, pagination, datatables

I am trying pagination Datatable with Node.js. Here is my Code HTML

```
<button id="btnSearch" type="submit" class="btn btn-responsive"><i class="icon-search"></i>&nbsp;Search</button>

<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
    <div id="tableContainer">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="dataTables1">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">base</th>
                <th class="text-left">base1</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
            <img id="loading-image" src="../dist/img/loading_spinner.gif" style="display: none;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is script code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        RefreshTable("#dataTables1");
    });

    function buildAjaxSourcUrl() {
        var orgURL = '?schemename=abc';

        if (orgURL.length > 1) {
            orgURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/statistic' + orgURL;
        } else {
            orgURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/statistic';
        }
        return orgURL;
    }

    function RefreshTable(tableId) {
        var urlData = buildAjaxSourcUrl();
        table = $(tableId).dataTable();
        table._fnClearTable(table.oSettings);
        table.fnDestroy();
        table.fnDraw(true);
        var table2 = $(tableId).dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            oLanguage: {
                sProcessing: "<img src='../dist/img/loading_spinner.gif'/>"
            },
            "aLengthMenu": [2, 30, 50, 100],
            "pageLength": 2,
            "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
            "sAjaxSource": urlData,
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": fnCallback
                });
            },
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'dataTables_wrapper'ip>>",
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",//"full_numbers",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "base1" },
                { "data": "base2" }
            ]
        });
    }
</script>
```

And here is my code server side node js

```
    exports.test = function(req, res) {
    console.log("test");

    var start = req.body.iDisplayStart;
    var pageSize = req.body.iDisplayLength;

    ManagerExport.getTotalUser(function(count){
        ManagerExport.getUser(start, pageSize, function(Users) {


            var response = {
                draw: 2,
                recordsTotal: count[0].count,
                recordsFiltered: count[0].count,
                data: Users
            };
            console.log(response);
            res.send(response);

        });
    });
}
```

in the view when i click on button search i get 2 records of user
[image]
after that i click on button index 2 then the page is stuck on processing, please suggest me a solution to fix this problem. Thanks for adventure

[image]

Comment: What is `console.log(response);` printing in your second request? Is it printing anything at all? `count[0].count` might be `undefined` and your response is never returned to the user.

Comment: the response is {"draw":2,"recordsTotal":24,"recordsFiltered":24,"data":[{"base1":40,"base2":"opening"},{"base1":38,"base":"opening"}]}

Comment: the count[0],count = 24

Comment: My response returned to the user but can't not bind to datatable

Comment: you can look my answer： [datatables stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394372/jquery-datatables-stuck-on-processing)

Answer (score 0):

That processing image shows up when bProcessing is true (which you specify in your constructor to datatable).  You can try setting the value to false after the ajax call returns to make it disappear.

Comment: but my paging not working the page still display first page

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you convert draw param to int before returning to datatable,
and return draw parameter according to param sent by datatable.

```
   def data=['draw':Integer.parseInt(params.draW),...]
    return data as JSON
```